# Flutter setState don't update UI when receiving data from kotlin

Tags: flutter, kotlin

I am learning about Inter-Process Communication (IPC) on android. I create 2 app (Client, server) sample projects using flutter.
When the client sends data to the server.
server successfully received data from koltin. and then i use methodChannel to call to dart and update UI(setState) with received data. But the UI at the server doesn't rebuild. both client and server app run on same android virtual machine. I guess flutter can't update the UI when the app is inactive.
Here is the code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const platform = MethodChannel('app.server.xzy');
  String data = 'Test';

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    platform.setMethodCallHandler(didRecieveTranscript);
  }

  Future<void> didRecieveTranscript(MethodCall call) async {
    final String utterance = call.arguments;
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    print('data = '+ utterance);
    setState(() {
      data = utterance;//don't work at here
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children:[
            Text(data, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26),)
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

anyone have this solution for this problem?

Comment: Widget need `Buildcontext` to be placed on widget tree. since you are calling the method inside initState, its only called 1 times. and if your `utterance` is update new value, the data is not updated except you re-run the statefullwidget

Comment: Can you explain more or have an example?